# Using a dropdown split button for 'Log In'

Tags: navigation, login, drop-down-list, cta

Something isn't sitting right but I can't tell what it is. I've not seen this pattern before.

Can you spot the UX/UI deficiencies in this proposed pattern? Or are you fine with it? This is found on the top right of the landing page in a website.[image: Login with a dropdown menu saying log in to account or continue with application]

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't understand what means "Continue with your application" in this case and how is it different from "Log into your account". It looks like two items have the same function. And how would the user continue with the application without login into it? So I'd say this UX is confusing and not helping to prevent errors.
Also, without the context, it's hard to understand what "Open account" means. "Register" or "Create an account" would be more up to standards.

Comment: Thanks yuliko. On this platform you have to apply for an account. If you stop mid-application, you can log back in to 'continue' the application. But then  another user needs to log back in to their actual account (as a verified user). It is very confusing, I agree. Does the context help?

Answer (score 0):

The question is first why to use a drop down, why not 3 buttons, we normally use dropdown when we have a bigger list to select from right?

Definitely it looks un-usual layout. Also the Open account looks like the focal point or a primary button, things to think here is "is "Open account" the primary call to action, should that be orange, should the primary button be dynamic and based on IP-address or some sort of data on first time or repetitive user should change the color". If the answer is no it should not be dynamic then should log in be primary button.

Also continiue with you application is not clear or implicit, should we rename it to be more clear?

Answer (score 0):

hard without the page and more context but ...

**I suggest you use tertiary cta, you have only 3 actions**

[image]

---

- or to move this other action on the page, maybe even think about
  before/after step.
- Sometimes on the login page, you can find 2 CTA and under the button a tertiary action. but you mention it's on navbar no?